# Macro to Disable 'Close Full Screen' in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I use code to run full screen in excel

And I turned off the esc button to prevent exit

**But I do not know how to disable the 'Close Full Screen' options menu in the right - click of the mouse**

```
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
```

'

```
Sub NoChange()
i = 0
End Sub

Sub NoEsc()
Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "NoChange"
End Sub
```

I'd love to get a way how to do it

If there is another way out of a full screen, please tell me

Comment: If I ever used an application that prevented me from exiting full screen mode, I would never use it again. This is ***horrible*** UX.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this? The "close full screen" option is somewhat hidden away, so if this is an issue, your users must be seeking the option... but why is this a problem?  What about when they [ALT]+[TAB] or [Windows]+[D] or [ALT]+[F4] etc?  Perhaps if you back up and explain the core issue that requires mandatory full screen, there are hopefully alternate (more user-friendly) ways that you can approach the issue...

Comment: One way to make users dislike using your application is to force UI setup like you're suggesting, but if you insist, Google "force full screen excel vba" and "remove item from context menu excel vba".  Keep in mind there can be inherent technical issues or other "side effects".  Also, these will probably affect all workbooks, not just the one.